# How to get the average value where a column value does not equal zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query

```
Select AVG(((cast(c.rating1 as Float)+ cast(c.rating2 as Float)+cast (c.rating3 as Float)+cast(c.rating4 as Float)+cast(c.rating5 as Float))/5))
From CSEReduxResponses c
Where 
     c.execoffice_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @today)-1, 0)
AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @today)-1, -1)
AND c.execoffice_status =1
AND C.rating1 <> 0 AND C.rating2 <> 0 AND C.rating3 <> 0 AND C.rating4 <> 0 AND 
C.rating5 <> 0
```

Where I'm getting the average of rating 1-5 but I'm also counting the ratings where equal '0'.

How can I get it to only count a rating where rating[x] does not equal '0' ?
It would still count but except of dividing it by 5 it will divide it by how many columns are not '0'.

I created a < http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/570fa/7 >

Comment: Your life would be easier if you normalised your schema: you have a "repeating group" that should be in its own child table each rating in a separate row

Comment: The specific expression depends on whether we're guaranteed that ratingN will always be non-NULL, or otherwise depend on how NULL values from `cast(ratingN As Float)` should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `VALUES` to get the average of non-0 values for each row.

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT AVG(rating)
    FROM (VALUES 
        (cast(c.rating1 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating2 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating3 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating4 as Float)), 
        (cast(c.rating5 as Float))
    ) AS v(rating)
    WHERE v.rating <> 0
) avg_rating
From CSEReduxResponses c
Where 
     c.execoffice_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @today)-1, 0)
AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, @today)-1, -1)
AND c.execoffice_status = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/570fa/26

I removed the following condition from your `WHERE`

```
AND C.rating1 <> 0 AND C.rating2 <> 0 AND C.rating3 <> 0 AND C.rating4 <> 0 AND 
C.rating5 <> 0
```

Because if you leave it in, you're only calculating averages for rows that have 5 non-0 ratings, which I'm guessing wasn't your intention.

To get the average of non-0 ratings across all rows divide the total sum of all non-0 ratings by the total count of non-0 ratings.

```
SELECT
    CAST(SUM(sum_rating) as float)/SUM(count_rating)
From CSEReduxResponses c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(rating), COUNT(rating)
    FROM (VALUES 
        (c.rating1), 
        (c.rating2), 
        (c.rating3), 
        (c.rating4), 
        (c.rating5)
    ) AS v(rating)
    WHERE v.rating <> 0
) AS x (sum_rating, count_rating)
Where 
    c.execoffice_date BETWEEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)
AND c.execoffice_status = 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/570fa/35

As others have mentioned, you should consider normalizing your table if possible.

Comment: In your second query, using CROSS APPLY [simplifies the code substantially](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/570fa/35 "Demo at SQL Fiddle").

Answer (score 2):

This is **not pretty** but should work:

```
  SELECT AVG((... SUM of 5 ratings ...) /
           (CASE WHEN rating1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
            CASE WHEN rating2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN rating3 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN rating4 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN rating5 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
```

After doing something like this one should feel appreciation for data normalization.

Comment: It seems like this expression may not return the specified result for NULL or negative values of ratingN. This expression does work if we are guaranteed all ratingN values are non-null and non-negative. (And in the edge case where the divisor is zero, MySQL doesn't throw a "divide by zero" error; that may be dependent on setting of sql_mode.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - OK. `WHEN rating IS NOT NULL and rating > 0` or `WHEN CAOLESCE(rating, 0) > 0`.  OP uses SQL Server 2008, not MySql.

Comment: or, **`WHEN rating1 <> 0`** would be sufficient.

Comment: @spencer7593 - Quite true.